# Is it efficient to join multiple dataframes using chained "join", rather than merge or concat?

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, concatenation

Not being an expert in code efficiency (yet) & best pythonic code writing (yet), I would like to ask the experts here if the following code is the best to `join` dataframes that have a common Date Index, or if merge or concat may be better:

```
data = df1.join(df2).join(df3).join(df4).join(df5).dropna()
```

I used the `.dropna()` suffix at the end to cancel out rows where a single `NaN` occurs.

NB: the reason why `NaN` occurs in this dataset is because I have created dataframes that are in fact shifted versions of other dataframes (using `.shift(n)` ), which means that `NaN`s creep in at the head of the shifted dataframes.

I intend to use this code in many other applications, so wanted to use the best possible methodology (i.e. not make unnecessary use of memory, take too much time to process, use the correct join/merg/concat constructs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be more efficient to do:

```
data = df1.join([df2, df3, df4, df5], how='inner')
```

This will merge all the dataframes in one go. It will also exclude any row that does not have values across all dataframes (so no need for `dropna()`). The default for `how` is `'left'`, which produces a row for every row in the calling dataframe, filling in any missing values with `NaN`. However, if any of the dataframes had `NaN` values in them before the join then you will still need to use `dropna()`.

You can also use `on=...` to choose which column(s) to join the dataframes on if you don't want to use the dataframes indexes.

Comment: Thank you so much @Dunes, that works a treat. I was unaware that one could feed an array of dataframes into the join call. FYI: because I have a low rep, I have upvoted your answer, however it doesn't show up on screen.